# Server behind modem not reachable, "connection refused"

Tags: ssh, router, bridge

I have a Clear modem and a Netgear router that I set up last week. I have a server behind the router. I was forwarding all traffic from the Clear modem to the router, and then SSH-specific traffic from the router to the server. It was working fantastically.

Now it says "connection refused".

Nothing has changed. The IP address (WAN) is the same, and I've got it hooked up to a dynamic IP service anyway. I can not figure this out at all.

My real problem is that I don't know how to check where the connection is getting refused. It is either at:

1. The Clear modem.
2. The Netgear router.
3. The server itself.

I have verified that I can SSH into the server from another computer on the same subnet.

How can I troubleshoot this to see where the traffic is getting refused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I spent 5 hours on this before giving in and calling Clear tech support. They told me they don't support looping back. I fired up an aircard from a different vendor and it worked fine.